# Java - Tic Tac Toe - Why won't my "switch player" method work?

Tags: java

Why does my switchPlayer() method only work once?  The method should work independently just fine, and when I put it inside my playGame() method after placeMark(), it works continuously, but that messes up my currentPlayer variable, which messes up other methods.  I do not want to make a player object, so I assume I am just missing something simple, like where to place the switchPlayer() method.

My result goes like this:

- *currentplayer 1*, place your mark.
- [places mark, all good]
- *currentplayer 2*, place your mark.
- [places mark, all good]
- *currentplayer 2*, place your mark.  // problem line.. doesn't switch
- [places mark, all good]

Relevant code for sub class:

```
public void playGame(){

    assignNames();

    assignMarks();

    explainGame();

    while(checkWin() == false && fullBoard() == false){

        getNum();

        placeMark();

        printBoard(); 

    }

    gameResult();

}


public void placeMark(){

    if(validNumber() == true){
        if(num == 1){
            board[0][0] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 2){
            board[0][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 3){
            board[0][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 4){
            board[1][0] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 5){
            board[1][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 6){
            board[1][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 7){
            board[2][0] = currentMark;    
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 8){
            board[2][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 9){
            board[2][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }


    }
}




public void switchPlayer(){

    if(currentMark == 'X')
        currentMark = 'O';
        else{
            currentMark = 'X';
        }


    if(currentMark == 'O' && playerMark1 == 'O'){
        currentPlayer = playerName1;
    }
        else{
            currentPlayer = playerName2;
        }
}
```

Relevant code for main class:

```
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();

    game.playGame();
```

It seems as though I should just post the whole code... so here it is.

```
public class TicTacToe {
        private static char[][] board;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        String entry;
        String playerName1;
        char playerMark1;
        String playerName2;
        char playerMark2;
        char currentMark;
        String currentPlayer;


public void playGame(){

    assignNames();

    assignMarks();

    explainGame();

    while(checkWin() == false && fullBoard() == false){

        getNum();

        placeMark();

        printBoard(); 

    }

    gameResult();

}


public TicTacToe(){

    board = new char[3][3];
    clearBoard();        
} // end TicTacToe()


public void clearBoard(){
    for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
            board[a][b] = ' ';
        }
    }
}// end clearBoard()


public void printBoard(){
    System.out.println("-------------");

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        System.out.print("| ");
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
            System.out.print(board[a][b] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------");
    }
}


    public boolean fullBoard() {

        boolean full = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                if (board[i][j] == ' ') {

                full = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return full;
    }


    public void explainGame(){

    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println("| 1 | 2 | 3 |");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println("| 4 | 5 | 6 |");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println("| 7 | 8 | 9 |");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println("The above board shows which numbers you must enter to place your mark in their respective locations.\n");
    System.out.println("Randomly assigning player marks. . .");
    System.out.println(playerName1+" will be Player "+playerMark1+", and "+playerName2+" will be Player "+playerMark2 + ".");
    System.out.println("Player X will go first.  Press any key to begin playing.");
    entry = input.nextLine();
}


public void assignNames(){

    System.out.println("Enter a name for Player 1.");
        entry = input.nextLine();
        playerName1 = entry;

    System.out.println("Enter a name for Player 2.");
        entry = input.nextLine();
        playerName2 = entry;
}


public void assignMarks(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(2);

    if( i == 0 ){
        playerMark1 = 'X';
        playerMark2 = 'O';
    }
    else{ 
            playerMark1 = 'O';
            playerMark2 = 'X';
    }

    currentMark = 'X';

    if(playerMark1 == 'X')
        currentPlayer = playerName1;
    else
        currentPlayer = playerName2;
}


public void switchPlayer(){

    if(currentMark == 'X')
        currentMark = 'O';
        else{
            currentMark = 'X';
        }


    if(currentMark == 'O' && playerMark1 == 'O'){
        currentPlayer = playerName1;
    }
        else{
            currentPlayer = playerName2;
        }
} 


public int getNum(){

    System.out.println(currentPlayer + ", place your mark (1-9).");

    num = input.nextInt();

    return num;
    }


public boolean validSpot(int num){

    boolean goodSpot = false;

    if(num == 1 && board[0][0] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 2 && board[0][1] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 3 && board[0][2] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 4 && board[1][0] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 5 && board[1][1] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 6 && board[1][2] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 7 && board[2][0] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 8 && board[2][1] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;
    if(num == 9 && board[2][2] == ' ')
        goodSpot = true;

    if(goodSpot == false){
        System.out.println("Input error.  Make sure the spot is not taken.");
    }

    return goodSpot;
}


public boolean validRange(int num){

    boolean goodRange = false;

    if(num >= 1 && num <= 9 ){
        goodRange = true;  
    }

    if(goodRange == false){
        System.out.println("Input error.  Make sure the number is between 1-9.");
    }

    return goodRange;
}


public boolean validNumber(){

    return ((validRange(num) && validSpot(num)));
}


public void placeMark(){

    if(validNumber() == true){
        if(num == 1){
            board[0][0] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 2){
            board[0][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 3){
            board[0][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 4){
            board[1][0] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 5){
            board[1][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 6){
            board[1][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 7){
            board[2][0] = currentMark;    
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 8){
            board[2][1] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }
        if(num == 9){
            board[2][2] = currentMark;
            switchPlayer();
        }


    }
}


public boolean checkSpot(char c1, char c2, char c3) {

    return ((c1 != ' ') && (c1 == c2) && (c2 == c3));

}


public boolean checkWin() {

    return (checkWinRows() || checkWinColumns() || checkWinDiagonals());
}


public boolean checkWinRows() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        if (checkSpot(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]) == true) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkWinColumns() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        if (checkSpot(board[0][i], board[1][i], board[2][i]) == true) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkWinDiagonals() {

    return ((checkSpot(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]) == true) || (checkSpot(board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]) == true));
}


public void gameResult(){

    switchPlayer();

    if(checkWin()){

        System.out.println("\nGAME OVER -- " +currentPlayer+ " WINS! WOO HOO!");
    }

    else if(fullBoard()){

        System.out.println("\nGAME OVER -- DRAW!");
    }
}


} // end TicTacToe
```

Comment: `"Why won't my switch player method work?"` -- No idea -- what happens when you run the program with a debugger? If you haven't done this yet, that's the best way to find the source of your error.

Comment: 1) What is playerMark1? 2) (Tip) you can write only the valid if in the placeMark function: board[(num-1)/3][(num-1)%3] = currentMark;

Comment: while(!checkWin() && !fullBoard()) {...}

Comment: In method `placeMark()' instead of `if` statement use `switch case` and call `switchPlayer()` only once after switch

Comment: It seems in method `switchPlayer()` playerMark1 check is unnecessary because u are not changing it, get rid of it and do `if(currentMark == 'O'){currentPlayer = playerName1; }`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 if(currentMark == 'O' && playerMark1 == 'O')
```

to

```
if(currentPlayer==playerName2)
```

Your code doesn't always work because it only changes to player one when both current mark = 0 and player1 mark = 0. This is, it only works when player one was assigned "O" in the beginning of the game.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! [how do I select a "best answer" to give you guys points?... or is that not an option

Answer (score 1):

The switch player code does nothing if both the current and player1 mark is X. Try:

```
if (currentMark == playerMark1){
  currentPlayer = playerName1;
} else {
  currentPlayer = playerName2;
}
```